# Actionscript 2.0 How to get keyPress working for number 1

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to get on (keyPress "<1>") working for my calculator so when I press one, the number one appears in the text box.

But there is no keyPress "<1>" for the number one, I heard there is something called KeyCode is needed, and I found the keycode for 1 is "49".

Can someone write the keyPress for the number 1?

Comment: when a key is pressed, you'd check if the keycode for that key matches what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Key event listener](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00001151.html).

```
var key:Object = {
    onKeyDown:function() {
        switch(Key.getCode()) {
            case 49:
                trace('key 1 is down');
                break;
            case 50:
                trace('key 2 is down');
                break;  
        }
    }
};
Key.addListener(key);
```

Then you can handle actions in the switch statement.